# App Menu Showing Blank Page

Tags: lightning

In more than one of my DE orgs, when I try to access the App Menu in Setup, nothing shows on the page. Normally you would see a list of apps, but in this case, there is nothing at all, not even the page title. The user I am using is the original one created in Trailhead and is a member of the System Administrator group. I have tried different browsers to no avail. I have other DE orgs that were also created in Trailhead that work just fine, so this doesn't make sense to me. If anyone
knows what is happening, please let me know because I am out of ideas!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This must have been some kind of back-end issue with Salesforce because the issue has suddenly been fixed. Weird!